# Can't retrieve properties file in maven resources

Tags: java, maven, properties, nullpointerexception, resources

```
public class LanguageUtil {

    public static Properties properties = new Properties();

    private void loadLanguageConfig(String filename) {

        try {
            String resourceName = "lang\\" + filename; 
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
                properties.load(resourceStream);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at <package>.testing.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
        at <package>.LanguageUtil.loadLanguageConfig(LanguageUtil.java:19)
        ... 5 more
```

Line 19 is "properties.load(resourceStream);"

I'm Trying to retrieve a file from the "lang" folder in my resources folder created by maven. When the jar builds I open the jar and the lang folder, as well as the file in the lang folder, is there.

**EDIT:** Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/679824/krishnan-mahadevan for the help! Changing the folder path of "lang\" to "lang/" fixed the problem.

Comment: Whats lang\\? A folder?

Comment: Can you please try changing `String resourceName = "lang\\" + filename; ` to `String resourceName = "/lang/" + filename; ` and see if that helps ?

Comment: That worked! Changing it from "lang\\" to "lang/" worked! It was working in IntelliJ before, and not in console. Now it works in both!

Comment: Please add self-answer. I will help others to search for unanswered questiosn

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by renaming "lang\" to "lang/"